# Magento - Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute_Data::factory()

Tags: magento-1.8, error

I have a big problem on my website.

A few days ago i started getting erros in my system.log. I already looked into them, but due lack of time it was sceduled for tomorrow.

But since now customers can't login anymore or retrieve the adress.

I did find where it went wrong.
In my checkout extension i had a wrong address line.

I had this code:

```
 <li class="d_3">
                <label for="billing:street1"><?php echo $this->__('Address') ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" title="<?php echo $this->__('Street Address') ?>" name="billing[street][]" id="billing:street1" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getAddress()->getStreet(1)) ?>" class="input-text required-entry" />
                </div>
            </li>
                            <li class="d_3">
                <label for="billing:street2"><?php echo $this->__('Housenumber') ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" title="<?php echo $this->__('Housenumber') ?>" name="billing[street][]" id="billing:street2" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getAddress()->getStreet(2)) ?>" class="input-text required-entry" />
                </div>
            </li>
                           <li class="d_3">
                <label for="billing:street3"><?php echo $this->__('Address Additional') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" title="<?php echo $this->__('Address Additional') ?>" name="billing[street][]" id="billing:street1" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getAddress()->getStreet(3)) ?>" class="input-text" />
                </div>
            </li>
```

But i saw i have used the wrong id in the last last ... it said 1 what should be 3 ...

I guess this was making my error's.
I restored it to original:

```
<?php for ($_i=2, $_n=$this->helper('customer/address')->getStreetLines(); $_i<=$_n; $_i++): ?>
            <br/>
            <li class="d_3">
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" title="<?php echo $this->__('Street Address '.$_i) ?>" name="billing[street][]" id="billing:street<?php echo $_i?>" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getAddress()->getStreet($_i)) ?>" class="input-text" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php endfor ?>
```

i get the following errors:

```
Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute_Data::factory() must be an instance of Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute, instance of Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute given, called in /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Address/Renderer/Default.php on line 114 and defined  in /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data.php on line 59

#0 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data.php(59): mageCoreErrorHandler(4096, 'Argument 1 pass...', '/var/www/vhosts...', 59, Array)
#1 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Address/Renderer/Default.php(114): Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute_Data::factory(Object(Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute), Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Address))
#2 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php(337): Mage_Customer_Block_Address_Renderer_Default->render(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Address))
#3 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php(326): Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract->format('html')
#4 /pathtomagento/app/design/adminhtml/default/quickcheckout/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml(163): Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract->getFormated(true)
#5 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#6 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#7 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#8 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#9 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#10 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#11 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('order_info', true)
#12 /pathtomagento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/tab/info.phtml(33): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('order_info')
#13 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#14 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#15 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#16 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#17 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#18 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Tabs.php(303): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#19 /pathtomagento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/tabs.phtml(38): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs->getTabContent(Object(Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tab_Info))
#20 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#21 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#22 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#23 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#24 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#25 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#26 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#27 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#28 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
#29 /pathtomagento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(58): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
#30 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#31 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#32 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#33 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#34 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#35 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#36 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#37 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(128): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#38 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->viewAction()
#39 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#40 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#41 /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#42 /pathtomagento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#43 /pathtomagento/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
#44 {main}
```

UPDATE 28-06-2015 - 22:30 (Europe/Amsterdam):

Everything works again ....
But i still get the error's in my `system.log`.
Does any one know what is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache and reindexing?

Comment: I have ... i did get my login possiblity back .... the developer output was on ... but i now only get this line in my `system.log` `Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute_Data::factory() must be an instance of Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute, instance of Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute given, called in /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Address/Renderer/Default.php on line 114 and defined  in /pathtomagento/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data.php on line 59` without the rest of the trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was solved by running the following SQL querry:

`UPDATE`eav_attribute`SET attribute_model = NULL WHERE attribute_id = '25'`

Comment: This does not sort the issue. Where did you get the ID 25?

Answer (score 4):

This error is related to table **eav_attribute**

You'll need to check column **attribute_model** for value **eav/entity_attribute**

Set this to NULL once you find the attribute code with this value

Sometimes it's the dob attribute code that throws up the error

Answer (score 0):

Correct solution is what @elfing said

DO NOT just set attribute_model to null on attribute_id 25 as what @Ronny said - this isn't guaranteed to be correct for your environment.

For me, I found the record by running the following:

```php
SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE attribute_code = 'eav/entity_attribute'
```

I then set the attribute_code to NULL on this record and it fixed my issue.

I was unable to view any orders from the Magento backend before.