# Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute_Data::factory() must be an instance of Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute

Tags: attributes, eav, ce-1.9.2.0

I'm facing this message in `system.log` when I open an oreder from the admin panel:

```
MESSAGE: Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute_Data::factory() must be an instance of Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute, instance of Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute given, called in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Info.php on line 133 and defined  in app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data.php on line 59
```

I have found [another question similar to this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/72434/22855), but it was related to a specific module and doesn't provide a general method to manage this error.
So, is there a way to act/a path that should be followed to find the problem and fix it? It looks like it prevents me from edit the order

Answer (score 0):

Open up PHPmyadmin

Locate `eav_attribute` table

Go to Search

`backend_model` **is not null**

Press **Go**

For all the results set `backend_model` as `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, but its resolved after run following query into my database :

```
UPDATE eav_attribute SET attribute_model = NULL WHERE attribute_id = '25'
```