# Argument 1 passed to Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute_Data::factory() must be an instance of Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, eav, vat, php-5.5

I'm having problems with the VAT field after a customer placed an order and entered a VAT number.

Everything appears to be working except when opening an order with a VAT number filled in. The following error shows up in the logs:

> Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute_Data::factory() must be an instance of Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute, instance of Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute given, called in .../app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Info.php on line 133 and defined  in .../app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data.php on line 59

The solution in a similar issue ([Magento - Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute_Data::factory()](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72434/magento-recoverable-error-argument-1-passed-to-mage-eav-model-attribute-data)) was to remove any `attribute_model`s from the `eav_attributes` table. This solution works until another order with a VAT number is placed. In that case the `attribute_model` for the taxvat is set to `eav/entity_attribute`.

I've looked through the Magento source where the VAT number might get saved but I couldn't find anything. What causes the `attribute_model` to be updated and is there any way to avoid it being set?

I'm running Magento v1.9.0.1 on PHP 5.5

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I'm facing the same issue